# Download tabular data as xlsx using xlsx npm package

Tags: javascript, npm, xlsx

I'm trying to download my json-like data as xlsx. I've used [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) npm package and followed some sample codes online but when I try opening the file in excel I get this error :
[image]

```js
/* original data */
var data = [{first: "Jack", last: "Wilshere"}, {first: "Tom", last: "Cleverly"}, {first: "Morgan", last: "Schneiderlin"}];


var filename = 'test.xlsx';
/* make the worksheet */
var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);

/* add to workbook */
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, filename);

/* write workbook (use type 'binary') */
XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.15.5/xlsx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a dependency problem use:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.15.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
```

instead and your code should work.